# is this too much load for an ajax scalable app?

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have a lobby that is supposed to refresh with the data of all the signed up players.
Currently I do this by having an ajax call that repeats every 3 seconds to keep the lobby-div as "live" as possible. The ajax call fetches a json with all the players information. With 25 signed up people, the parsed json would look like this:

```
{
"0": [
    "Dummy Player.6935",
    "Dummy Player.3476",
    "Dummy Player.8299",
    "Dummy Player.9591",
    "Dummy Player.7282",
    "Dummy Player.4067",
    "Dummy Player.4818",
    "Dummy Player.1396",
    "Dummy Player.4198",
    "Dummy Player.4244",
    "Dummy Player.5060",
    "Dummy Player.3496",
    "Dummy Player.5932",
    "Dummy Player.2524",
    "Dummy Player.6162",
    "Dummy Player.1828",
    "Dummy Player.7738",
    "Dummy Player.9144",
    "Dummy Player.4312",
    "Dummy Player.9270",
    "Dummy Player.5935",
    "Dummy Player.9523",
    "Dummy Player.4090",
    "Dummy Player.6803",
    "Dummy Player.9576"
],
"1": [
    "6",
    "3",
    "2",
    "7",
    "2",
    "9",
    "4",
    "2",
    "5",
    "6",
    "3",
    "5",
    "2",
    "5",
    "7",
    "2",
    "8",
    "1",
    "2",
    "1",
    "5",
    "2",
    "5",
    "9",
    "1"
],
"2": [
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "1",
    "0",
    "1",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "1",
    "0",
    "0",
    "1",
    "1",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0"
],
"3": [
    25,
    "3",
    "7",
    "2",
    "1",
    "5",
    "2",
    "2",
    "1",
    "2"
],
"4": [
    "0",
    "0",
    "4",
    "0",
    "0",
    "2",
    "3",
    "1",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "1",
    "0",
    "4",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0"
]
```

}

The json is created by a .php file which lays on the server.

Is this too much load if 25 people have the website open at the sametime and everyone is having the json requested ?

Is there any way I can try this out ? If I create 25 browser tabs, is that the same as if 25 ppl from around europe would have the website loaded ? It's the first time I am doing webdeving, so I still have no real clue how to test it.

Comment: try,  ab -n 100 -c 10 http://yoursite.com/  , in your terminal .   This command will create 100 connections to your server with one concurrency level of 10 connections at the same time

Comment: Not likely... This isnt all that much data at all. If your base server can handle 25 requests a second you should be fine.

Comment: If your server can handle 25 requests / second, than you are good to go.